# iOS Dev - Adding Storyboard Manually

Tags: ios, storyboard

I've created an iOS app for iPhone and it's been released and working. I'm now revisiting it to support native iPad format. I've changed the project type to universal and added a new iPad storyboard, plus a Objective-C class (.h, .m) to go with it but I can't seem to link the class and the storyboard.

For instance I can't Ctrl - Drag items into new class from storyboard to use them at objects. How to do you about adding new storyboard's and the classes to go with them to a iOS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to create outlets or actions by control-dragging unless you've set the view controller object in your storyboard to have the same class as the new view controller class you have created (in the identity inspector).

Also, I don't know your specific requirements but it is often better to use the same view controller class for both iPad and iPhone and just branch where you need it.

Comment: I would be happy to use the same view controller class but not sure how to go about it. For example if I add a label to the iPad storyboard then how do I link that label to the previous label outlet (called dispalyResult) so that when the method that sets displayPassword fires it will set it on either iPad or iPhone. I also tried just Ctrl + Drag to create a new outlet and then brach code but it doesn't work because I haven't set view controller object to be sdame as view controller class as I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

The Storyboard is just a container for your scenes (View Controllers, Nav Controllers, TabBar Controllers, etc).  You associate a class with a scene (VC, NC, TBC, etc).  What you want to do is add a View Controller or a NV, TBC, etc depending on your desired application flow.  Then you will associate that with your parent class you created.

All you have to do then is make sure you are checking the type of device using something like this:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
     // iPad 
}
else
{
     // iPhone or iPod touch.
}
```

And set the Storyboard for iPad in the Application Summary

Answer (score 1):

Isn't better to do a class for iPhone named for example: ITViewController
and an other one named ITViewControllerHD who gonna inherit from ITViewController and overload each necessary classes for avoid the repetition on this code:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
 // iPad 
}
else
{
 // iPhone or iPod touch.
}
```

I think it's cleaner :/